# RESTful API endpoint naming

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm working on a asp.net core 2.2 backend exposing a RESTful API.

The current implementation works fine (additional code removed for clarity):

```
namespace Sppd.TeamTuner.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ITeamTunerUserService _userService;
        private readonly ITokenProvider _tokenProvider;
        private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public UsersController(ITeamTunerUserService userService, ITokenProvider tokenProvider, IAuthorizationService authorizationService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
            _authorizationService = authorizationService;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetByUserId(Guid userId)
        {
            // TODO: secure this call
            var user = _userService.GetByIdAsync(userId);
            return Ok(_mapper.Map<UserDto>(await user));
        }
    }
}
```

The single API method works fine with URL https://localhost:5001/Users?userId=4AF29C4A-282A-4FB8-8691-9D44398A97F2

Now I would like to add a second method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByTeamId(Guid teamId)
{
    // TODO: secure this call
    var users = _userService.GetByTeamIdAsync(teamId);
    return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserDto>>(await users));
}
```

Which would result in URL https://localhost:5001/Users?teamId=4AF29C4A-282A-4FB8-8691-9D44398A97F2 (note that parameter is teamId instead of userId compared to first call).

When testing with SwaggerUI, the page doesn't load and following exception is being shown:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.NotSupportedException: HTTP method "GET" & path "Users" overloaded by actions - Sppd.TeamTuner.Controllers.UsersController.GetByUserId (Sppd.TeamTuner),Sppd.TeamTuner.Controllers.UsersController.GetByTeamId (Sppd.TeamTuner). Actions require unique method/path combination for Swagger 2.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.CreatePathItem(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, ISchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.CreatePathItems(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, ISchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String documentName, String host, String basePath, String[] schemes)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Questions:
- Is this a SwaggerUI issue? Meaning would the controller work otherwise?
- Should the Users or the Teams controller expose the method to get all team users? We query by team id and return users.
- If it remains in the Users controller, what's the 'best' way to have unique endpoints?

Comment: I would put it in Teams controller and receive it by using route like /teams/1/users - where 1 is team id. This is more "rest" :). But if you want to keep it in the Users controller then annotate teams action with [Route("action-name/{teamId}")] and access it by using Users/action-name/{teamId}

Comment: @Ismar Thanks, I'm using your first proposition (even if my IDs, which are GUIDs, do not look too nice in the URL: https://localhost:5001/Teams/B699ED14-F672-46F5-885E-460EE8381802/users

Comment: Yeah, that's the URL you see in log or some tools but important is that your definition is REST friendly, at least that's my opinion. Your action route definition probably is something like "{teamId}/users" and that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Precisely, I'm using "{teamId}/users". I fully agree with what you said. As I'm pretty new to designing such an API, I prefer asking early in order to set the base right. Btw if you want to post an answer I'll mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put it in `Teams` controller and receive it by using route like `/teams/1/users` - where 1 is team id. This is more "rest" :). You will need to annotate your Teams controller action with `[Route("{teamId}/users")].`

However, if you want to keep it in the Users controller then annotate teams action with `[Route("some-action-name/{teamId}")]` and access it by using `users/some-action-name/{teamId}`

Answer (score 1):

```
you need to provide action name in your url.which is unique path
```

like this  https://localhost:5001/Users/GetByTeamId?teamId=4AF29C4A-282A-4FB8-8691-9D44398A97F2

Answer (score 1):

you can give `Attribute Routing` a try, here's what I mean

```
[HttpGet("/{userId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByUserId(Guid userId)

[HttpGet("/{teamId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByTeamId(Guid teamId)
```

`[HttpGet("/{teamId}")]` defines a new `route` with param `teamId`

Comment: This would have been my prefered solution, unfortunately it doesn't work: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: 'The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

Comment: you can't have it like that because at runtime there will be two actions receiving Guid which comes after the controller name. You have to differentiate between those 2 by using hardcoded string values in action route name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add action to your route attribute , don't forgot to add action name to your url

```
namespace Sppd.TeamTuner.Controllers
{
   [Authorize]
   [ApiController]
   [Route("[controller]/[Action]")]
 public class UsersController : ControllerBase
 {
     private readonly ITeamTunerUserService _userService;
     private readonly ITokenProvider _tokenProvider;
     private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;
     private readonly IMapper _mapper;

     public UsersController(ITeamTunerUserService userService, ITokenProvider tokenProvider, IAuthorizationService authorizationService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        _authorizationService = authorizationService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByUserId(Guid userId)
    {
        // TODO: secure this call
        var user = _userService.GetByIdAsync(userId);
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<UserDto>(await user));
    }
  }
}
```